# how to use object attribute value for method name ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a two mailers

```
welcome_manger(user)  welcome_participant(user)
```

Both send different information and have different layouts.

when I call the deliver method I would like to use something like the following

```
UserMailer.welcome_self.role(self.user)
```

This does not work. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
m = 'welcome_' + self.role
UserMailer.send(m.to_sym, [self.user])
```

Assuming that `self.role` returns a String.

The [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000999) method invokes a method by name:

> **`obj.send(symbol [, args...]) → obj`**
>   Invokes the method identified by *symbol*, passing it any arguments specified.

So you just need to build the appropriate method name as a string and then convert it a symbol with [`to_sym`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001176).